# How can I make variables from option:selected in PHP $_POST?

Tags: php, jquery, sql

**I need to make few variables in PHP from selected options, each variable for each selected option **

**I am trying this:**

```
<?php 
    $tag1 = $_POST["select_name[option:selected(1)]"];
    $tag2 = $_POST["select_name[option:selected(2)]"];
    $tag3 = $_POST["select_name[option:selected(3)]"];
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
<select name="select_name[]" multiple>
```

then your $_POST['select_name'] holds an array, just loop over it

```
$options = $_POST['select_name'];
for($i = 0; $i < count($options); $i++) {
   ${"tag$i"} = $options[$i];
}
```

Comment: And how to loop over it? Thank you so much!

Comment: Check my edit, it works, just note that creating variables that way is not pretty. Why do you need seperate variables like that?

Comment: I need to store them to SQL DB, like: tag_1,  tag_2, tag_3 ... Thank you!